# ¿Cómo puedo ocultar un botón en base a una condición con jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sql-server

Tengo un botón que se llama "anular", que está ubicado en un modal, y se ve así
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<button id="modal_btn_anular" type="button" class="btn btn-warning d-none">Anular</button>
const modalBtnAnular = $("#modal_btn_anular")
```

Entonces, al presionarlo, cambia un valor en mi base de datos, y IdEstado se pone en "8" que significa "anulado" es decir 8=anulado

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en la vista del html se ve así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero, es que al estar la base de datos en ese estado anulado, es decir idEstado=8, el botón "anular" se oculte. Yo estuve tratando con esto con jquery:

```
if (solicitud.estado == "Anulado") {
            modalBtnAnular.removeClass("d-none")
        }
```

Pero no me funcionó, no me da ningún error, pero no me funciona. ¿Tendrían alguna idea de como hacerlo? Estoy trabajando con jquery y sqlserver

Comment: Intenta removerlo del DOM y no remover la clase `modalBtnAnular.remove()`

Comment: Si le quitas la clase `d-none` es cuando lo muestras, pues `d-none` en bootstrap es lo mismo que `display: none;` en CSS.  Si acaso debes agregarle esa clase, no quitársela, aunque por defecto parece que ya la tiene, o eso parece.

Comment: Deberias agregar la estructura de la informacion que usas para armar tu table, y tambien el codigo de tu tabla para poder ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Eso lo puedes hacer desde el **back**, supongo que generas dicha información desde un **for**, pero como no mencionas nada al respecto se puede hacer de la forma mas compleja, que es comprobar que la pagina se haya cargado totalmente y mediante un id en el cuerpo de la tabla accedemos al contenido de la tabla **"data"**.

```js
//FUNCION QUE DETECTA LA CVARGA COMPLETA DEL DOM
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  //OBTENEMOS EL BODY DE LA TABALA CON ID DATA QUE ES LA PARTE QUE NOS INTERESA
  var table = document.getElementById('data');
  //OBTENEMOS FILAS
  for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    //OBTENEMOS COLUMNAS
    for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
      // console.log(col)
      //console.log(row.children[1].textContent)
      //ACCEDEMOS A LA CELDA MEDIANTE LOS NODOS PARA OBTENER EL TEXTO Y COMPROBAMOS
      if (row.children[1].textContent == 'Anulado') {
        //ACCEDEMOS A LA POSICION DEL BOTON Y MODIFICAMOS ATRIBUTO SI LA CELDA DE SU FILA ES ANULADO
        row.children[2].children[0].disabled = true;
      } else {
        //SI ES CREADO SE MANTIENE EL BOTON ACTIVO
        row.children[2].children[0].disabled = false;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>ESTADO</th>
      <th>ACCION</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="data">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Anulado</td>
      <td><button class="accion">boton</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Creado</td>
      <td><button class="accion">boton</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Anulado</td>
      <td><button class="accion">boton</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Anulado</td>
      <td><button class="accion">boton</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Creado</td>
      <td><button class="accion">boton</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Creado</td>
      <td><button class="accion">boton</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Esta función sera ejecutada al cargar tu pagina por completo, y si se agrega o modifica una fila mas esta la tomara en cuenta, ya que es dinámica, dime si te ayudo.

**NOTA:** En el if donde asigno **disabled:true o false** es donde tu debes agregar o remover tu clase si lo haces con **bootstrap**.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo, lo unico que tienes que hacer es cambiar el atributo display de block a none en el button dependiendo de si el estado es = 8:

```
if (solicitud.estado == "Anulado") {
   $("#modal_btn_anular").css("display","none");
}
else {
   $("#modal_btn_anular").css("display","block");  
}
```